# does not have permission to run the dbo.TempGetVersion stored procedure

Tags: sql, asp.net, session-state

I had my .net application in 3.5 framework which I migrated to .net 4.5.2. Application is installed in One Azure VM & DB(with sys admin privilege) is in another Azure VM. When I am running my application I am getting below error displayed.
“Unable to use SQL Server because either ASP.NET version 2.0 Session State is not installed on the SQL server, or ASP.NET does not have permission to run the dbo.TempGetVersion stored procedure. If the ASP.NET Session State schema has not been installed, please install ASP.NET Session State SQL Server version 2.0 or above. If the schema has been installed, please grant execute permission on the dbo.TempGetVersion stored procedure to either the ASP.NET application pool identity, or the Sql Server user specified in the sqlConnectionString attribute.”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net session state mode "SQLServer"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380423/asp-net-session-state-mode-sqlserver)