# Change Schema in SessionState for ASP.Net Web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, session-state

I have a legacy web application written in ASP.Net Web forms using SQLServer for State management. Recently, I have to host the application on a shared hosting server. After configuring the application, whenever I am trying to access the application, it throws me the below error -

```
Invalid object name 'bidcr94t.dbo.ASPStateTempSessions'.
Invalid object name 'bidcr94t.dbo.ASPStateTempApplications'.
```

In new server where I am hosting, I do not have anything rleated to bidcr94t and want to change the same in my application.

I tried running the code `aspnet_regsql.exe -S YourServerName -d YourDatabaseName -ssadd -E -sstype c`
as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53869790/729768) but it throws another error as below which is correct because I am on shared hosting and my user doesnt have access to msdb database

> An error occurred during the execution of the SQL file 'InstallSqlState.sql'. The SQL error number is 229 and the SqlException message is: The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_delete_job', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
> If the job does not exist, an error from msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job is expected.

Please advise solution to this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not switch to using in-proc for session-state? Using SQL Server for session-state storage only makes sense in web-farm scenarios - which is less necessary today as modern hardware is capable enough that a single-instance box can handle loads previously only web-farms could do. And if you _do_ need a web-farm because of load, then your load-balancer will almost certainly support cookie-based host affinity which eliminates another reason to use SQL Server-based session storage.

Comment: Most of the old ASP.NET design does not consider sharing hosting scenarios. So, you either need a dedicated SQL Server instance for your web app, or a dedicated environment with both IIS/SQL Server. Like the other comment indicated, you might not even need to use SQL Server for sessions.

Comment: In the legacy mode, I have to rely on SQLServer instead of InProc. Also, do not want to work on changing codes and then fixing things. So, looking for options to install this on shared hosting

Comment: I would consider running the script/command to create the session database on your local computer. Once you verify that the session database was created correctly, then consider scripting out that database, and then run that script on the server. You THEN have to check/see/test/look at the connection string you specified for the session database in your web config,and ensure that it works, and that you can connect to the database. But you want to first ensure the session db was and is being created. You could even save as a sql backup and restore on the server, but scripting is easier.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I tried doing the exact thing you mentioned, but for some reason, its not working with that approach. I believe its more on the DB name part, somewhere linked.

Comment: Test local - setup session db. If that works, then transfer that database to the existing instance of SQL server you have running on the hosted site. You have to of course change and set and ensue that the session DB has a user for the logon to be used here. So, either the session db not being created, or you don't have a user created for the connection string to use.  Add a test page with some code to open/test if the session DB works, and post that test page to the site - see if it can connect and use the session DB.  it not clear how you transferring the db to the production site.

Comment: Locally everything works. When moving the database to server, it fails. Tried thrice. Changed machineKey as well, refreshed connection strings to ensure doing the right thing. Db connectivity works, just the state db connectivity doesnt work.